# Unable to Properly Add References for Citrix to C# Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, xenapp

I am trying to build an application for Citrix users to end their own session.
I originally coded this myself, but then I found this post:

[C# How do I log off a Citrix XenApp User Session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118799/c-sharp-how-do-i-log-off-a-citrix-xenapp-user-session)

But I am unable to emulate it.
When I add the **using Citrix;** references, I am seeing "The type or namespace could not be found."

Do I need to install something for this?
I have searched the internet for this, but all I could find was a download for what is apparently the XenServer-SDK (is this correct?)

Even then, I added the .dlls in Visual Studio, and references like so:

```
 using CookComputing;
 using XenServer;
```

However, I am seeing the same message for these (they are not recognised by Visual Studio).

My original solution does work, but I think I may be able to program a much cleaner solution by using APIs.

Please can someone point me in the right direction? Any help on this is much appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to stop XenApp session, then you need XenApp SDK (not XenServer). You can download SDK from [Citrix site](https://www.citrix.ru/downloads/xenapp/sdks.html).

Then in your project add references to dlls located in `%ProgramFiles%\Citrix\XenApp Server SDK\bin` (for XenApp 6.0):

- Citrix.Management.Automation.dll
- Citrix.XenApp.Sdk.dll
- other dlls depending on what you will use

And then add `using` directives to your .cs file:

```
using Citrix.Common.Sdk;
using Citrix.XenApp.Sdk;
using Citrix.XenApp.Commands;
using Citrix.Management.Automation;
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail, many thanks for your response - this was extremely helpful and I feel I now understand a bit more about reference dlls and using directives. I have been able to accomplish what I need using the regular windows CMD command terminal, but this is not ideal due to the terminal flashing up for a second in some instances. When I try logging off users using your above suggestion, I am seeing this error:  Citrix commands must be executed at the Citrix server or using remoting. Assuming I am missing some security setting which is required for remote control. Thanks again!

Comment: As a message says, you have two choices: create local Powershell Runspace and use Citrix Remoting (Citrix supports it's own remoting), or create Powershell Runspace remotely on Citrix XenApp server and run local commands (local on that server). I haven't tried this, so you better try yourself and open a new question if you'll got stuck with it.